# Read system call taking forever on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a TCP server application in c++.

I'm trying to read a line one char at a time from a socket, but the read() system call never returns.

```
string buffered_reader::read_line() {
    string str;
    int i = 0;
    char ch;

    do {
        int len = conn.read_from_conn((void*)&ch, 1);
        if (len == -1)
            throw string("Error reading from connection!");

        str += ch;
    } while (ch != '\n');

    return str;
}
```

And here is the read_from_conn() function

```
int connectionplusplus::read_from_conn(void *buffer, int buffer_len) {
   return read(this->connfd, buffer, buffer_len);
}
```

Comment: Use `strace` to verify what syscalls are made.

Comment: You can use `read()` in unblocking mode as well, depends on how you open the socket.

Comment: What about the case where read() returns 0 ? Make sure you handle that .  What if the other end doesn't send any data, ? That said, there are many cases where read() will never return, and the only way out is to do non.-blocking I/O and employ a timeout on reading data.

Comment: "read(0, " is the output from strace

Comment: Is "connfd" properly initialized? fd 0 is usually stdin, unless you know for sure that you closed stdin.

Comment: How is your sender retrieving the characters it is sending? Have you checked the sender to see if it is actually sending something? Is your sender waiting for a complete line of input before having characters to send?

Comment: thanks kfsone that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that connfd wasn't initialized.